# What was the source of inspiration behind the character Sasuke in Naruto?

Tags: naruto

Like the title says, where did Mr. Kishimoto got the idea of the character personality, backstory, name etc.?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Sasuke Uchiha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasuke_Uchiha#Creation_and_conception) article on Wikipedia, Sasuke's name comes from Sarutobi Sasuke, a fictional ninja featured in Japanese children's stories. Kishimoto also once said that Sasuke's character was influenced by Hiei from YuYu Hakusho.

Comment: please site your sources

Comment: Here i thought they were inspired by goku and vegeta. doh.